# Run map reduce job with 3rd party dependency in Jar

Tags: java, maven, jar, mapreduce, maven-shade-plugin

I am trying to test if I can jar 3rd party dependencies into my jar, SSH the jar over to a remote machine, and then run a map reduce job.

Process:

With my project, I run `mvn clean package` and that produces the files `my-appy-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` and `original-my-appy-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`. I scp the first file over to my remote machine and run the command:

```
hadoop jar hadoop my-appy-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar  /user/bli1/wordcount/input /user/bli1/wordcount/output
```

I also tried:

```
hadoop my-appy-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar WordCount /user/bli1/wordcount/input /user/bli1/wordcount/output
```

I'm not sure why I am getting this error:

`Error: Could not find or load main class my-appy-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

[image]

pom.xml:

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.18.1</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
              <artifactSet>
                <excludes>
                  <exclude>org.hamcrest:*</exclude>
                  <exclude>org.mockito:*</exclude>
                  <exclude>org.objenesis:*</exclude>
                </excludes>
              </artifactSet>
              <filters>
                <filter>
                  <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                  <excludes>
                    <exclude>META-INF/LICENSE</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/license</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                  </excludes>
                </filter>
              </filters>
              <transformers>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                  <manifestEntries>
                    <Main-Class>com.mycompany.app.WordCount</Main-Class>
                    <Build-Number>1</Build-Number>
                  </manifestEntries>
                </transformer>
              </transformers>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Answer (score 1):

Open your *.jar file and check it's MANIFEST.mf file. It should contain the "Main-Class" row with your class with "public static main()" method. If there is no "Main-Class" add it yourself

This link will help you do this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html

Comment: I am using the shade plugin and I think all I need to do is declare it in my pom.xml:` <Main-Class>com.mycompany.app.WordCount</Main-Class>`. Please correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 1):

you need to give full path to main class including package name.

```
hadoop my-appy-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.mycompany.app.WordCount /user/bli1/wordcount/input /user/bli1/wordcount/output
```

Answer (score 0):

The command you run through jar file is as below:
hadoop jar jar_filename.jar package_name.class_name HDFS_inputfile_name HDFS_output_directory

Your command should be

hadoop jar my-appy-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.mycompany.app.WordCount /user/bli1/wordcount/input /user/bli1/wordcount/output